# Export Specific Page from MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

We have an internal document wiki running on MediaWiki (latest stable). Is there a way we can export a specific page for a customer without giving them access to the entire wiki (which is currently behind a PAM-based authentication).

Edit1: Sorry for the vagueness, I meant is there a way to syndicate a specific page so that they don't actually have access to the wiki but the content is still available and up-to-date.
For example, the page I want them to see http://mysite.com/wiki/page_to_see
Can I have it available at http://mysite.com/outsite_wiki

Comment: Export, like giving them a snapshot of the current content or like giving them continues access to the actual page? Is the authentication handled directly by Mediawiki or by the web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have locked down the permissions on all the other pages so that you have to login to see them, you can add the page you want the customer to see to the white list. See http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgWhitelistRead

Answer (score 1):

Any specific format you're looking to export to?

You could try the [**PDF Export**](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Pdf_Export) extension that allows you to view a page as a PDF.

Alternatively, you could simply install one of the meriad tools that let you print to a PDF and print out the page from a browser.